# translating in english 转发两个，会有久违的惊喜

Tags: translation

can someone please give me an exact translation of 转发两个，会有久违的惊喜 in english. it is about a book story of a girl and a guy who have not contacted in a week.
can someone also tell me if the girl is missing the guy.

Comment: 转发两个，会有久违的惊喜
bkrs: 转发: retransmission; transmit; repeat; relay:
转发文件 transmit a document 久违:(haven’t done sth) for a long time
a long time since we last met
haven't seen for a long time
 
(套) How long it is since we last met!; I haven't seen you for ages 惊喜: nice surprise
to be pleasantly surprised, 会有久违的惊喜 will be pleasant surprise to meet again after such a long time

Comment: can you give me the english translation only? becasue your message is all over the place thanx by the way

Comment: 1st 3 lines supply translation of parts making up the given passage, last 12 words translate part after comma, first part may depend on context

Comment: may I know if this sentence was used in past tense,present tense or future tense? and also the thing that was 转发两个 was sending a peach fruit. did she sent it or someone send to her or unknown? thank you

Comment: w/o context it would seem to mean: sending (relaying, forwarding) 2 (peaches) will be a pleasant surprise after being w/o contact (nothing having happened) for such a long time (unknowable who is sending the peaches)

Comment: "Forward these two pieces of messages, you would get long-waited surprise".

Comment: 久违 means  "have been absented for a long time"

Comment: I think that no surprises. ^_^.

Answer (score 5):

I quote from @dan from the comments: "Forward these two pieces of messages, you would get long-waited surprise". This may have nothing to do with the main story.

And I will also add some background which I guess would be relevant here:

Now, in China, in some (many) social media, like WeChat, Weibo, etc., there are always posts/articles that encourage a reader to re-post it. (I would treat most of such posts as spam though.) So you will often see a message like "you will get a reward if you re-post it twice" or something like that, which is unrelated to the content of the post. Most of the time the said reward/surprise in the message is not real (you will not get such reward/surprise even if you re-post). (And you may even see messages like "you will get cursed if you read but do not re-post".)

I do not know if this phenomenon also exists in other parts of the world.